# yes/no input loop, issues with with correct looping

Tags: python, loops

I'm programming  a short guessing game. But, I have no idea how prevent incorrect input (yes/no), preventing user to go forward. Here's a WORKING code. Tried with while True but it only messes the input even more. The furthest is that else, that notifies the player, but the q count move forward.

```
# -*- coding: cp1250 -*-

import sys

def genVprasanja ():

    yes = set(['yes','y', ''])
    no  = set(['no','n'])
    testQ = ['hello1', 'hello33112', 'hello332', 'hello2', 'hello4','hellomore', 'ANSWER', 'hello1', 'hello33112', 'hello332', 'hello2', 'hello4','hellomore', 'ANSWER2', 'hello1', 'hello33112', 'hello332', 'hello2', 'hello4','hellomore', 'ANSWER3'] 
    points = 5
    total = 0
    for x in range(0,3):
        for y in xrange(len(testQ)):
            reply = str(raw_input('\n'+str(abs(y-5))+ ' - ' +  testQ[y]+' (y/n) --> ')).lower().strip()
            if reply in yes:
                print '\ncorect!\n\nAnswer is :',testQ[5], '\n\nPoints: ',points, '\n'
                total = total + points
                print 'Total: ', total, '\n'
                break                    
            elif reply in no:
                points = points - 1      
                if points !=  0:     
                    print '\nwrong!', '\n\nNext question for: ',points                                     
                else:
                    print '\nThe end!\n\n' 'Every anwser is wrong!\n\nYou got 0 points.\n\Correct answer is:', testQ[5],'\n\n'
                    total = total + points
                    print 'SKUPNE TOČKE: ', total
                    break
            else:
                sys.stdout.write("\nPlease press 'RETURN' or 'N'\n")
    points = 5
genVprasanja()
```

Edit:

Every player gets to answer three sets of 5 questions. They receive questions until they say yes. If they say no 5 times the loop ends (3x times) - I'm using `var points` to count.

But if they input and incorrect words (not no and not yes) the input question repeats itself asking them again (until they enter a valid answer). After that they get THE SAME question they failed to validly answer.

Comment: Soooo much whitespace...

Comment: You need to indent the body of the function.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I was breaking down the code, and I forgot to remove the ws when posting....

Comment: `raw_input()` returns a string, you don't need to use `str()` to convert it to a string.

Comment: `if (reply not in yes) and (reply not in no): continue`, where `continue` repeats the loop

Comment: Yeah, had some problems with that, but the issue is that I would like to repeat the input loop until either yes or no is input. What happens now is the code still runs, even thought there's an `else`

Comment: `if (reply not in yes) and (reply not in no): continue` this is not working, the code is repeating, but the question count is still rising.

Comment: You don't have an input loop. You just have a loop for each question.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, but I can't seem to succeed. I tried with 'while' but I didn't seem to get it to work. been at it 4 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while True:` will work, you need to `break` out of the loop once the conditions have been met.

```
while True:
    reply = str(raw_input('\n' + str(abs(y - 5)) + ' - ' + testQ[y] + ' (y/n) --> ')).lower().strip()
    if reply in yes or reply in no:
            break
```

Based on the updated scope, try this, it seems the `break` may have caused you issues:

```
reply = False
while reply not in yes and reply not in no:
    reply = str(raw_input('\n' + str(abs(y - 5)) + ' - ' + testQ[y] + ' (y/n) --> ')).lower().strip()
```

Comment: This kinda works, but now if I press yes, it starts with a new question but not with the first one on the list. same goes for 'no'. it goes all to the last one, and begins with the last one for another set.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you are trying to achieve, could you please explain a little more about how you want your program to run.

Comment: What should happen if I say yes and what should happen if I say no?

Comment: The program asks the user max 5 questions (the 6th question is the answer). If the user says YES to any of them, the loop stops at that point. After that he gets to more sets of 5 questions. Same rules apply.

But if he says no, he gets all the questions from the set (until he reaches five questions, 


If the user says yes, the loop breaks and then he gets two more sets of questions (imagine that list has 12, 18, or more entries). But if he says no

Comment: Could you update your question to reflect this, it is a little tricky to follow.

Comment: ups, too soon. Basically the user is getting max 5 question (the last one ends the loop, because it's the answer).  from 5 points to 0 points. every wrong answer (no) gives him an additional question. until he gets all five (the loop ends), for three sets.  suppose he types in an incorrect input, he's supposed to get the last question he failed to input yes or no, again.

Comment: The else part works now, but if I write 'y' it shows results and starts the same location on the list + further (for every yes).
if i say 'no' it goes from first location to the last (for each 6 items on a set).

Answer (score 0):

You need a 'while' in here somewhere, once you hit the end of the 'for' block it will go to the next value in the range.

```
for y in xrange(len(testQ)):
    bGoodInput = False
    while not bGoodInput:
       reply = str(raw_input('\n'+str(abs(y-5))+ ' - ' +  testQ[y]+' (y/n) --> ')).lower().strip()
       if reply in yes:
           ...
           bGoodInput = True

       elif reply in no:
           ...
           bGoodInput = True

       else:
           ...
```